# What's the point of using ENUM in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, enums

I've been digging in `enum` in TypeScript and it got me thinking what's the point of using it. I'm not questioning the value of it. It's just that I'm unfamiliar with the usage of it and which has been leading me to code like declaring some sort of a bunch of objects which keeps constants used throughout the application without using `enum`. To sum up, what's the point of using it and difference than just using/declaring manual objects which keeps some constants? Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Enums is handy to force type validations (not easy with constants) and it's easy to convert a readable enum to a number and vice a versa.

```
enum Access {
  Read = 1,
  Write = 2,
  Execute = 4,
  AnotherAccess = 8
}
```

I use it all the time when I have a set of choices, to make it clear what kind of values the code accept and for code readability

```
if( myAccess == Access[Access[myaccess]] ) // enum used
```

Bitwise operations is another thing, eg, my accesses is (Access.Read | Access.Execute)

```
var myAccess = Access.Read | Access.Execute; //instead of 1 | 4 = 5

// do I have write access?
if ( (myAccess & Access.Write) > 0) { /* yes */ }

// do I have read and execute 
if ( (myAccess & (Access.Read | Access.Execute)) > 0) { /* yes */ }
```

Comment: But if the type validation is your main object, wouldn't it be more 'TypeScript-y' to declare `Type` for that? Plus, why is it good to be able to convert a readable enum to a number?

Comment: 1. readable enum to number is handy for bitwise operations. 2. enum shows up perfectly in intellisens where type does not.

Comment: Thanks for the example above! It helped a lot :)

Answer (score -2):

Your question seems to me that is not `TypeScript` related but generic in terms of why one would use `enums` and not `constants` at any language. So just google and you will find a lot of things. One quick look I had was: https://gorbeia.wordpress.com/2015/03/11/java-enums-vs-constants/

If you ask me `enums` are simply a better way to organize your code.

If your question is `typescript` related please give some more details of what is different at `enums` in typescript i.e. in `java`.

Comment: Actually, the question is not just limited to TypeScript. I've asked it because I'm currently using TS. Thanks for the link! One question though: What do you mean by `a better way to organize my code`?

Comment: Better in what way? Please, be specific if you answer the question.

Comment: @Eduard Constants are "loose" values not attached to anything. Enums are "grouped", attached to something meaningful. E.g. `UP` and `DOWN` vs `Direction.UP` and `Direction.DOWN`